# MessageMessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jax-rs

I am trying to execute a very simple REST API using JAXrs. I have been following JetBrains tutorial and I'm stuck at the point where the API needs to return Reponse/XML. The java version used here is 1.8 and the Tomcat is 10.0.

I Guess there is some dependencies missing. Can someone help?

Here are my code snippets:
`pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.surender</groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>messenger</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>messenger</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.1.0-M2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Model Class

```java
package org.surender.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Surender")
public class MessagesModel {

    @XmlElement(name = "Message ID")
    public int messageId;
    public String messageTxt;
    public String messageLike;
    public String messageComment;
    
    
    public MessagesModel(int messageId, String messageTxt, String messageLike, String messageComment) {
        super();
        System.out.println("Objects getting created");
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.messageTxt = messageTxt;
        this.messageLike = messageLike;
        this.messageComment = messageComment;
    }
    
    public MessagesModel() {
        
    }

    public int getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }


    public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }


    public String getMessageTxt() {
        return messageTxt;
    }


    public void setMessageTxt(String messageTxt) {
        this.messageTxt = messageTxt;
    }


    public String getMessageLike() {
        return messageLike;
    }


    public void setMessageLike(String messageLike) {
        this.messageLike = messageLike;
    }


    public String getMessageComment() {
        return messageComment;
    }


    public void setMessageComment(String messageComment) {
        this.messageComment = messageComment;
    }
    
}
```

Message Service

```java
package org.surender.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.surender.model.MessagesModel;

public class MessagesService {
    public List<MessagesModel> getMessages() {
        List<MessagesModel> messagesList = new ArrayList<MessagesModel>();
        messagesList.add(new MessagesModel(1,"Hey There !","2","Hello"));
        messagesList.add(new MessagesModel(1,"Hola Amigo!","2","Hello"));
        return messagesList;
    }
    
    public MessagesService() {
    }
}
```

`MessageResource`

```java
package org.surender.messenger;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.surender.model.MessagesModel;
import org.surender.service.MessagesService;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("messages")
public class Messages {
    MessagesService msgService = new MessagesService();
   
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getMessages() {
        System.out.println("Hi... I'm here one");
        GenericEntity<List<MessagesModel>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<MessagesModel>>(msgService.getMessages()) {};
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;` You're using `javax`. Should be `jakarta`

Comment: If you are using a Jakarta container, you should remove anything (dependencies) that has `javax` in the name. It will save you a lot of headache